# Does Android Eclipse plug in not recognise Integer resource types

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

If I follow the example code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer) for an Integer resource in Android (/res/values/integers.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="max_speed">75</integer>
</resources>
```

and then look at it using Android Resource Editor (Resources tab) it shows up as an "Unknown XML Attribute" and I can't edit it.

This code works fine to retrieve it.

```
Resources res = getResources();
int maxSpeed = res.getInteger(R.integer.max_speed);
```

Is this just something Google left out accidentally? It recognises Integer Arrays no problem.
I'm using the latest versions of the Eclipse plugin (v 10).

And while on the topic, I'm curious why Android only supports Integers and not other number types

Comment: I don't know why, tried your code with same results, but it seems there is an another Resource Type not mentioned at that link, ITEM, and there you can define it of type Integer. Something like: *<item type="integer" format="integer" name="maxspeed">32</item>*

Comment: That's very interesting Adinia. Thank you. I love learning little things like this.